# How to distance and to MDS-plot objects according their complex shape

Tags: r, dimensionality-reduction, distance-functions, multidimensional-scaling, manifold-learning

Suppose I have **four basal forms** of signal (blue, purple, red, green). I also have created ***transition* forms** between each other. If you carefully look on the picture below, you can see that for example blue signal (*A1*) slowly transforms into purple  (*A5*) - horizontally, or into red (*E1*) - vertically.  Taken in general, **the closer is the difference between any two signals the more similar they are**.

I am looking for some **method/algorithm/technique** which is able to:

1. **Extract as much information as possible about complexity of signals**
2. **Map signals into 2D (or 3D) according to their similarity**

[image]
*Link to source data:* each signal is coded into JPG image (25 jpg files, each 100x180 pixels)
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ynidcsjdymrh85f/AAAHVtYSG0GUvX3CEdDWWG42a

---

***I have spent some time trying to solve this issue, so here I add my approach, which does no yield desired result:***

At first, I've set working directory, **load all 25 jpg-files into a R list**...

```
setwd("add directory where you downloaded jpg-files here")

# required libraries
library(jpeg)
library(raster)
library(asbio)

sgnl.vctr<-c("A1.jpg","A2.jpg","A3.jpg","A4.jpg","A5.jpg",
             "B1.jpg","B2.jpg","B3.jpg","B4.jpg","B5.jpg",
             "C1.jpg","C2.jpg","C3.jpg","C4.jpg","C5.jpg",
             "D1.jpg","D2.jpg","D3.jpg","D4.jpg","D5.jpg",
             "E1.jpg","E2.jpg","E3.jpg","E4.jpg","E5.jpg") 

sgnl.list <- list()      # sgnl.list contains all 25 signals
for (i in 1:length(sgnl.vctr)){
sgnl.list[[i]] <- readJPEG(sgnl.vctr[i])
}
```

I had some problems with pixel values (range from 0 to 1), therefore I **recclassify them into binary**. (either 0 or 1).

```
# reclassification of values
for (i in 1:25) {
sgnl.list[[i]][1:100,1:180,1][sgnl.list[[i]][1:100,1:180,1] > 0.5]<- 2
sgnl.list[[i]][1:100,1:180,1][sgnl.list[[i]][1:100,1:180,1] <= 0.5]<- 1
sgnl.list[[i]][1:100,1:180,1][sgnl.list[[i]][1:100,1:180,1] == 2]<- 0
}
```

Then, I've **extracted** binary (0-1) vectors from each jpeg-file. *If someone know how to shorten procedure bellow, please edit the R-code.*

```
# A row
A1<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[1]][1:100,1:180,1])
A2<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[2]][1:100,1:180,1])
A3<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[3]][1:100,1:180,1])
A4<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[4]][1:100,1:180,1])
A5<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[5]][1:100,1:180,1])
# B row
B1<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[6]][1:100,1:180,1])
B2<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[7]][1:100,1:180,1])
B3<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[8]][1:100,1:180,1])
B4<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[9]][1:100,1:180,1])
B5<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[10]][1:100,1:180,1])
# C row
C1<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[11]][1:100,1:180,1])
C2<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[12]][1:100,1:180,1])
C3<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[13]][1:100,1:180,1])
C4<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[14]][1:100,1:180,1])
C5<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[15]][1:100,1:180,1])
# D row
D1<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[16]][1:100,1:180,1])
D2<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[17]][1:100,1:180,1])
D3<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[18]][1:100,1:180,1])
D4<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[19]][1:100,1:180,1])
D5<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[20]][1:100,1:180,1])
# E row
E1<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[21]][1:100,1:180,1])
E2<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[22]][1:100,1:180,1])
E3<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[23]][1:100,1:180,1])
E4<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[24]][1:100,1:180,1])
E5<-as.vector(sgnl.list[[25]][1:100,1:180,1])
```

**Vectors were compared** by `Kappa` function to obtain **total agreement value**. See this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534192/how-to-compare-all-possible-combinations-of-objects-in-r-by-loop/24534794#comment37992299_24534794
*(Many thanks to @digEmAll)*

```
# looping of:
#            Kappa(sgnl.list[[1]][1:100,1:180,1],
#                  sgnl.list[[2]][1:100,1:180,1])$ttl_agreement
M <- rbind(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,
           B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,
           C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,
           D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,
           E1,E2,E3,E4,E5)

res <- outer(1:nrow(M),
             1:nrow(M),
             FUN=function(i,j){
               # i and j are 2 vectors of same length containing 
               # the combinations of the row indexes. 
               # e.g. (i[1] = 1, j[1] = 1) (i[2] = 1, j[2] = 2)) etc...
               sapply(1:length(i),
                      FUN=function(x) Kappa(M[i[x],],M[j[x],])$ttl_agreement )
             })

row.names(res) <- c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5",
                    "B1","B2","B3","B4","B5",
                    "C1","C2","C3","C4","C5",
                    "D1","D2","D3","D4","D5",
                    "E1","E2","E3","E4","E5")
colnames(res) <- c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5",
                   "B1","B2","B3","B4","B5",
                   "C1","C2","C3","C4","C5",
                   "D1","D2","D3","D4","D5",
                   "E1","E2","E3","E4","E5")
```

Finally, similarity matrix (`res object`) was used for **multidimensional scaling**...

```
# mds based on ttl_agreement matrix
d <- as.dist(res)
mds.coor <- cmdscale(d)
plot(mds.coor[,1], mds.coor[,2], type="n", xlab="", ylab="")
text(jitter(mds.coor[,1]), jitter(mds.coor[,2]),
     rownames(mds.coor), cex=0.8)
abline(h=0,v=0,col="gray75")
```

However, as you can see (left plot), **four basal signals were not separated as I expected**. Does anybody know better solution which would lead to desired outcome (right plot)?

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that you didn't use clustering. You used multidimensional scaling (mds). So, was the whole question about mds, i.e. about plotting the distances between the 25 shapes in euclidean space?

Comment: If yes, then two question arise. First, why did you expect that 2d map will be sufficient? Or is 2d was the strict requirement of yours? Given that you have 4 focal propotypes, they may well require 3d space. Second, the problem may be with the chosen proximity measure. Did you consider more alternative measures, not just "kappa"? Selecting proximity measure is crucial.

Comment: Hi @ttnphns! Yes, I would like to plot the distances between the 25 shapes in euclidean space. 2D map is not strict requirement. I would just prefer it over hierarchical clustering (tree branches). Do you know any better proximity measures than Kappa?

Comment: I never analyzed images, and I'm not `R` user. Did I understand it right, that all images, of equal pixial size, you take as X-Y coordinates data, binary (0 for white pixel, 1 for black pixel). Then you unwrap X-Y into a single column (vector) and compute some proximity measure (called 'kappa") between each pair of vectors (i.e. images).

Comment: Yes @ttnphns. That is exaclty what I have done.

Comment: One crucial moment. Can shapes be improperly aligned wrt each other? Shitf by just one pixel will be devastating. Consider two identical vectors `0101`. If the alignment is shifted, such as `-0101` vs `0101-`, the similarity is 0!

Comment: I am aware of this possibility, however it is highly unlikely to cause problems with this particular dataset. I was very careful when creating JPG's - the alignment is NOT shifted. (minimal agreement via Kappa is approx. 74%)

Comment: If you are sure that the alignment is fully the same, that saves much effort... OK. I'd compute [Dice](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/55802/3277) coefficient instead of Simple matching coefficient (which you call "kappa"). Matrices of all such _binary matching coefficients_ can be [efficiently computed](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/49477/3277) via matrix algebra. Then I'd input `1-Dice` (called Bray-Curtis distance) into MDS program and tried 2d and 3d metric and nonmetric solutions.

Comment: P.S. Why Dice and not Simple matching? Well, `0-0` (i.e. white-white) match is of no importance for you, it only interfere. Also, `1-1` match is the same importance as _either_ `1-0` and `0-1`, no matter what of those. That's why. (Sorry I won't go chatting, I have to go now.)

Comment: In any way, comparing such shapes by binary matching coefficients based on pixel data is not the only and not the best approach. One could compare the shapes as histograms are compared, for example...

Comment: As far as I can see--I did not read through the code--your four "basal forms" can be represented as high-dimensional vectors and the "transitions" lie in their convex hull, which is a three-dimensional simplex. Doesn't your question (2) boil down to projecting any arbitrary signal onto that simplex?  This is easily done with the least squares solution (constraining the coefficients to be positive and sum to unity). Then you will need to decide an appropriate map of that simplex into 2D or 3D; I don't see that you provided any criteria for uniquely determining such a map.

Comment: Hi @whuber! Thank you for reaction. As soon as I understand to your comment, I will respond. :D

Comment: @whuber, You're saying interesting things. May you wish to post a full answer?

Comment: @whuber should you want to blow my answer out of the water (:)), If I understand you correctly what you suggest can perhaps most conveniently be achieved in R with smacofConstraint in smacof. There is an option external that allows fitting onto a simplex of given dimensions. E.g. with `simpl <- smacofConstraint(res,constraint="unique",external=list("simplex",4),ndim=2); plot(simpl)`. The result doesn't look like what the OP needs, but I suppose to fix the basal points to the vertices of the simplex one needs to define a user-defined specified `constraint`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be only a partial answer because **I don't think the plot that you expect is really what is in the data**, especially the "parallelity and continuity" of the intermediate signals. I will speculate on reasons for that below.

But I think **I was able to get to what you look for in terms of the four basal signals A1, A5, E1, E5**. Namely that they lie on the edge of the embedded manifold, that opposite signals lie more or less diametrical to each other (that is A1, E5 and E1, A5 respectively) and that neighbouring signals are preserved (so A1, A5 and E1, E5 respectively).

Generally, I think standard (i.e. with an input weight matrix consiting of only 1's) MDS doesn't really give you what you want because you are actually looking for **nonlinear dimension reduction that has some localization feature, namely that larger "distances" should not be preserved but local distances should**. There are a [number of algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction) that do that. A rather popular one that is often used for cases like yours is called t-SNE for [**t-Distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding**](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/19j49/t-SNE.html). On the linked homepage you will find quite some information.

I calculated the t-SNE embedding for your kappa distance. Note that I use a high perplexity to force a shaping that looks like the one you aim for. It can be obtained by

```
set.seed(1)
library(tsne)
tsne.coor1 <- tsne(res,perplexity=25)
rownames(tsne.coor1) <- c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5",
                   "B1","B2","B3","B4","B5",
                   "C1","C2","C3","C4","C5",
                   "D1","D2","D3","D4","D5",
                   "E1","E2","E3","E4","E5")
plot(tsne.coor1[,1], tsne.coor1[,2], type="n", xlab="", ylab="")
text(tsne.coor1[,1], tsne.coor1[,2],
     labels=row.names(tsne.coor1), cex=0.8)
abline(h=0,v=0,col="gray75")
```

and looks like this

[image: t-SNE embedding]

The basic signals are labeled in red. As you can see, the similarity structure as captured by your preprocessing and distance measure does not suggest that the intermediate signals are actually at all as you expect them to be. For example, the path from A1 to E1 has intermediate signals E4, D5, A3 and not B1 through D1. But this is what your data tell you! So, the similarity between the signals that are within the convex hull of the embedded manifold suggests that the clear-cut pattern is not preserved.

There are two obvious explanations:

1. Some information gets lost in mapping to low-D. The information that gets lost might actually be the information you were looking for.
2. The distance measure might not capture what you actually care for. I agree with @ttnphns on this one.

**[\Edit]** (thanks @ttnphns!) 
To investigate the last point, I tried other measures of similarity for binary matrices. For this high perplexity it led to no discernably different results in the shape, *but it did so in the arrangements* (I used a gravity model similarity and an asymmetric binary similarity, the one returned by `dist(x,method="binary")`). For lower perplexity the effects on the visualisation the kappa distance is small, but for the other distances it is not. To illustrate for the asymmetric distances the results are:

```
res <- dist(M,method="binary")
set.seed(1)
tsne.coor2 <- tsne(res,perplexity=25)
tsne.coor3 <- tsne(res,perplexity=3)
rownames(tsne.coor2)<-rownames(tsne.coor3) <- c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5",
                   "B1","B2","B3","B4","B5",
                   "C1","C2","C3","C4","C5",
                   "D1","D2","D3","D4","D5",
                   "E1","E2","E3","E4","E5")
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(tsne.coor2[,1], tsne.coor2[,2], type="n", xlab="", ylab="")
text(tsne.coor2[,1], tsne.coor2[,2],
     labels=row.names(tsne.coor3), cex=0.8)
abline(h=0,v=0,col="gray75")
plot(tsne.coor3[,1], tsne.coor3[,2], type="n", xlab="", ylab="")
text(tsne.coor3[,1], tsne.coor3[,2],
     labels=row.names(tsne.coor2), cex=0.8)
abline(h=0,v=0,col="gray75")
```

and here's the results

[image: different distance matrix t-SNE]

So, for high perplexity the difference in the shape of the projection of the signals is rather similar for both distance measures. For lower perplexity, the results change. Note that while it is looking different than what you originally intended *when using the asymmetric binary distance, the transition from basis signal through the other states seems to be better preserved in the low perplexity plot, particularly column-wise!* . This makes the speculation 2 of using kappa being a not very suitable distance measure more likely. You may try the distances `dist(x, method="binary")` or `cluster::daisy(x, metric= "gower"))` (which is the dice coefficient, I think).

**[\end Edit]**

Note the t-SNE has random initializations, so it might look a bit different at your end --- not sure whether `set.seed` has an effect in the R implementation. The random initialization is actually something that might get you closer to what you need anyway. As the authors put it:

> In contrast to, e.g., PCA, t-SNE has a non-convex objective function. The objective function is minimized using a gradient descent optimization that is initiated randomly. As a result, it is possible that different runs give you different solutions. Notice that it is perfectly fine to run t-SNE a number of times (with the same data and parameters), and to select the visualization with the lowest value of the objective function as your final visualization.

You may play around with the above mentioned distances and some of the parameters, especially perplexity, to perhaps get you closer to what you need into one direction or the other. Hope this helps as a first start.

Comment: +1. For `has some localization feature, namely that larger "distances" should not be preserved but local distances should`, however, one could note that MDS - good implementations - provide option to weight input distances. So, one can put more weight (importance) for small ones. But, in any case, a good distance function must be crucial. I was somewhat upset that t-SNE (which's new to me) `led to no discernable different results`.

Comment: @ttnphns Re: Input weights-this is a good point. I edited the answer accordingly. Re: no discernably differences of t-SNE with different distances. I found that curious too. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere, I didn't investigate it further. But I set the perplexity parameter quite high here (to 25) to force this type of shape. If one uses smaller perplexity, the results are different for different distances, see the edit.